# Semantic-ui vs metro-ui-css

Tags: semantic-ui, metro-ui-css

after looking for good Framework, Semantic UI seems to be good alternative but :

- no recent update in Github (development stopped ?)
- no feed back except 5 - 6 bad for responsive / customisation capacities
- no really concrete example of site which use it

So, despite good documentation and great example of using in official site, I'm wondering about this framework.

My need, developping Web Site for school. I'm looking for framework : responsive, with ready-in-use components and with customisation capacities for making funny site.

https://metroui.org.ua/v4/index.html is aplha version but promising too.
With it : active dev and "high level" components like calendar, carousel. 
I think it may be serious challenger for my use.

So semantic-ui or metroui according you ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I made tests with Semantic UI and I think use it.
Couple Semantic UI / TinyMCE seems great : easy customization / integration.

Only negative point for : using responsive grid in "manual mode" (one definition  by device) is more complicated / wordy

Anyway, I'm following Metro CS 4.0 ;-)